# CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser custom right context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser v41.0.1 in my project. 
When I right click into webbrowser, default right context menu only have a few items.

[image: default right context menu]
I want to customize it's right context menu, e.g add Reload function...
But I can't find any way to do that.

Somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that feature is no available in the current release version (`41.0.1`).

A PR was merged recently that adds that functionality.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1219

It will be available in the next `-pre` release which should be out shortly.

Comment: `43.0.0-pre02` is up on `nuget.org`