# C# Cefsharp download image when you right click on the image

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Currently, in my browser, when you right click on anything, also an image, then you only get these:
[image]

but I also want a save image button, maybe even copy link adress or copy image.
How do I do that?

Comment: Well, [according to this 4 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453054/cefsharp-winforms-chromiumwebbrowser-custom-right-context-menu), you can't customize it.  I don't know if the answer has changed.

Comment: Is it still possible to make a feature to download images?

Comment: Here's a [more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251796/cefsharp-oncontextmenucommand-get-menu-label), but its in VB.Net.  \

Comment: I'm not super proficient with CefSharp.  I'm just trying to find other questions that might help you.

Comment: That question doesn't really help. Maybe not add it to the right click menu, maybe somewhere else, it doesn't really matter atleast you'll be able to download images.

Comment: You customise the menu via http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_IContextMenuHandler.htm See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/75/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs for example of adding custom items

Answer (score 1):

Carlos Delgado has a fantastic post on ourcodeworld.com which explains how to modify the context menu:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/449/how-to-add-new-items-to-the-native-context-menu-on-a-cefsharp-control-in-winforms

I used his example to add these items to the context menu:

```
public class MyCustomMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
{
public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
{
    // Remove any existent option using the Clear method of the model
    //
    //model.Clear();

    Console.WriteLine("Context menu opened !");

    // You can add a separator in case that there are more items on the list
    if (model.Count > 0)
    {
        model.AddSeparator();
    }


    // Add a new item to the list using the AddItem method of the model

    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26501, "Show DevTools");

    // Add a separator
    model.AddSeparator();


    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26503, "Open in Paintbrush");
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26504, "Open in Excel");
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26505, "Run Script..");
```

...... etc

Then removed the View Source option:

```
model.Remove((CefMenuCommand)132); // View Source
```

And then just for fun threw in these options, which are not in the menu by default:

```
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)113, "Copy"); 
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)100, "Back"); 
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)101, "Forward"); 
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)102, "Reload"); 
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)103, "Reload No Cache"); 
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)131, "Print");
```

Then have some fun with it

```
public void SaveImage(string imageUrl, string filename, ImageFormat format)
{
    System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient();
    System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl);
    Bitmap bitmap; bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        bitmap.Save(filename, format);
    }

    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
    client.Dispose();
}


public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
{
    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26501)
    {
        browser.GetHost().ShowDevTools();
        return true;
    }

    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26502)
    {
        browser.GetHost().CloseDevTools();
        return true;
    }

    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)113) // Copy
    {

        if (parameters.LinkUrl.Length > 0)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(parameters.LinkUrl);
        }
        if (parameters.MediaType == ContextMenuMediaType.Image )
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(parameters.SourceUrl);
        }



    }

    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26503) // Open in paintbrush
    {

        if (parameters.LinkUrl.Length > 0) {

            Clipboard.SetText(parameters.LinkUrl);

        }
        if (parameters.MediaType == ContextMenuMediaType.Image)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(parameters.SourceUrl);

            string subPath = @"C:\temp";

            string fn = @"C:\temp\temp.bmp";

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

            SaveImage(parameters.SourceUrl, fn, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            Process.Start(fn);

        }
    }



    // React to the third ID (Display alert message)
    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26503)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An example alert message ?");
        return true;
    }

    // Any new item should be handled through a new if statement


    // Return false should ignore the selected option of the user !
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Using the actual enum values would be much nicer http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_CefMenuCommand.htm it's only necessary to cast an int for the user defined items. Also using WebClient will fail if the image require authentication, using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_StartDownload.htm if you need to use the CEF download mechanism.